# Run Python Module from Source (Obtained via GitHub)

Tags: python, git, github, scikit-learn

I am missing a key piece of understanding regarding the workflow needed to contribute to larger open source projects on the GitHub platform, and I am hoping someone may be able to explain.

Essentially, I'd like to understand how to contribute to the [scikit-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn) repository.  I am clear on how to fork the repo, update my local copy, submit pull requests, etc.  What I do not understand is how to run my local version of scikit-learn.

Put another way, how to I ensure that when I run:

```
import sklearn
```

It will reference the local sklearn stemming from my local clone, and not the standard sklearn obtained via pip?

Please forgive any inaccuracies in terminology or articulation in my question description.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tests for local use [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), if you can use python3 [pyvenv](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/venv.html), to enable use `source bin/activate`

then use the command install scikit-learn

You can see the code if you have doubts `cd lib/python3.4/site-packages`

Answer (score 3):

You can get the path from which the module is loaded by doing

```
print(sklearn.__path__)
```